# linux rearange field and sort by column

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, csv

I have (tab-separated) input files:

```
id1    id2    ....

id1    id3    ....

id3    id4    ....

id2    id1    ....

id3    id4    ....

.....
```

I need to

1. rearrange `col1` and `col2` by numerical sort.  For now I do this in a python script.
2. sort by `col1` then `col2`. For now I am doing this by taking the output of the python script and using GNU `sort`.

My question is the following: is there a way to merge step 1 and step 2 (using GNU sort or any other GNU/Linux command-line tools)?

Is there an efficient alternative GNU/Linux command for step 1?

```
result:

id1    id2    ....

id1    id2    ....

id1    id3    ....      

id3    id4    ....

id3    id4    ....

.....
```

My code actually works, I am looking to improve its speed.

Here's the Python program:

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='')
parser.add_argument('-blast', help='input', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-out', help='output', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()


def get_tmp():
# return a name for temporary file.

    dir = os.listdir(".")
    cpt = 0

    name = "tmp_{}".format(cpt)

    while name in dir:
        cpt += 1
        name = "tmp_{}".format(cpt)

   return name

# get a temporary name
tmp_name = get_tmp()

# open inputfile in reading and output in writing
with open(args.blast) as input_blast, open(tmp_name, 'w') as tmp_file:

    for line in input_blast:

        spt = line.strip().split()
        tmp_file.write('\t'.join(sorted(spt[0:2]) + spt[2:]) + '\n')

# sort by field one and two
child = subprocess.Popen("sort -k1 -k2 {} > temps_sort && mv temps_sort {}".format(os.path.abspath(tmp_name), args.out),shell=True)
child.wait()
```

Comment: PS no need to create your own temp-file handling. python standard library has a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use an external file and command. Python can sort strings just fine, unless the file is too big

something like this should work

```
def rearrange_ids(file):
    pattern = re.compile(r'id(\d+)')
    for line in file:
        spt = line.strip().split()
        if spt:
            ids = sorted(int(pattern.findall(id_string)[0]) for id_string in spt[0:2])
            yield ids, '\t'.join(['id%i' % i for i in ids] + spt[2:]) + '\n'

with open(input_file, 'r') as file, open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
    output_lines = sorted(rearrange_ids(file), key=lambda x: x[0])
    output_file.writelines(line for ids, line in output_lines)
```

> ```
> id1   id2 ....
> id1   id2 ....
> id1   id3 ....
> id3   id4 ....
> id3   id4 ....
> ```

## edit

I changed my original algorithm because id did not keep the original order when comparing, and sorted `10` before `2`